# Is cipher "3des-ctr" supported by openssh?

Tags: openssh, sshd

Is cipher "3des-ctr" supported by openssh?

It is not mentioned in the list of supported ciphers in the man page of `ssh_config`:

> ### Ciphers
>
> > Specifies the ciphers allowed for protocol version 2 in order of preference. Multiple ciphers must be comma-separated. The supported ciphers are ''3des-cbc'', ''aes128-cbc'', ''aes192-cbc'', ''aes256-cbc'', ''aes128-ctr'', ''aes192-ctr'', ''aes256-ctr'', ''arcfour128'', ''arcfour256'', ''arcfour'', ''blowfish-cbc'', and ''cast128-cbc''. The default is:
> >
> > > > aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,
> > > >         aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,
> > > >         aes256-cbc,arcfour

Comment: Make sure to properly format your question next time, please. I've done it for you now.

Comment: No problem, I just found it quite unreadable, and only via google search found what your last paragraphs are :)